# CMake Could NOT find PythonLibs but (found version "2.7.6")

Tags: python, cmake

I've got CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(PythonInterp REQUIRED)
find_package(PythonLibs REQUIRED)
```

When CMake runs it finds PythonInterp but can't find PythonLibs. It produces an error:

```
Make Error at c:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:108 (message):
Could NOT find PythonLibs (missing: PYTHON_LIBRARIES) (found version "2.7.6")
```

How can I solve this problem? 
I can add that Python is installed in directory

```
C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.6.4\python-2.7.6.amd64
```

and as you see it is x64 version.

Comment: Did you append C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.6.4\python-2.7.6.amd64 to your Path environment variable?

Comment: Yes, I did. It didn't help. What's more I reinstalled WinPython and it finally works. Still I don't know why after first installation it didn't work.